# Program terminated with signal 8, Arithmetic exception with blosc

Tags: c

Please refer the following stack trace:

```
_Program terminated with signal 8, Arithmetic exception.
#0  0x00007f6cba9fe187 in blosc_run_decompression_with_context () from   /usr/lib64/libblosc.so.1
(gdb) bt
#0  0x00007f6cba9fe187 in blosc_run_decompression_with_context () from /usr/lib64/libblosc.so.1
#1  0x00007f6cba9fe35c in blosc_decompress_ctx () from /usr/lib64/libblosc.so.1_
```

It seems that the function `blosc_run_decompression_with_context()` did not check the `context->blocksize` whether is zero, which will be divided.

Please focus the line 1421 of c-blosc/blosc/blosc.c

```
context->blocksize = sw32_(context->src + 8);      /* block size */
```

the `context->block size` is possible to be zero.

How to fix this?

Comment: It seems to me the +8 should move outside the parenthesis as sw32(I think) is swapping endian of context->src, it seems safer to do any addition after the swap is done.

Comment: the sw32() will swapping endian of context->src array from index 8 to 12.